# Yeoman, scripts sources vanish at build

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I've got this Gruntfile.js generated by yeoman-generator-angular : http://pastebin.com/tAACSy3M

It never has produced (even before any customization) code in `script.sha.js`.  Things in scripts source folder just vanish in my `build` folder at `grunt build` task.

I don't understand the `concat` task executed with `build`. Where it is in the Gruntfile.js ? Because it execute things according to the terminal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a good night to think...
I needed to learn how works grunt-usemin.
My HTML tag was incorrect because I forgotten to change `<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->` to `<!-- build:js({.tmp,src}) scripts/scripts.js -->`.
So, well, I think before the modification of this in my Gruntfile it worked... :/